# Почему я вижу ошибку"В типе "City[]" отсутствуют следующие свойства из типа "City""?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux

Возникла проблема с типизацией. Сам фильтруемый массив объектов `'cities'` имеет тип `City[]` - соответственно там имеются все перечисленные ключи типа `City` (текст ошибки после примера с кодом). Мне нужен один объект типа `City` чтобы задиспатчить его для дальнейшего использования в других компонентах.

Ошибка:

> /* const x: City
> В типе "City[]" отсутствуют следующие свойства из типа "City": title, lat, lng, zoom */

Код:

```
function LocationItem ({city}: LocationProps): JSX.Element {
      const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
      const x: City = cities.filter((el) => el.title === city);
```

Answer (score 1):

Используя `.filter` вы получите массив всех элементов, прошедших условие.
Если вы хотите получить один элемент, воспользуйтесь `.find` (не забываем, что он вернет null, если ничего не найдет):

```typescript
function LocationItem ({city}: LocationProps): JSX.Element {
      const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
      const x: City | null = cities.find((el) => el.title === city);
```

Если же вам нужно получить массив всех совпадений, то у переменной `x` должен быть тип `City[]`.

```typescript
function LocationItem ({city}: LocationProps): JSX.Element {
      const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
      const x: City[] = cities.filter((el) => el.title === city);
```